# Robust linear regression for group differences

Tags: r, regression, anova, t-test, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to understand what it means when a p value for a grouping variable is < 0.05 after running robust linear regression.

Does this mean that the 2 groups significantly differ with respect to the dependent variable?

How is this method conceptually different from running a simpler anova?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Q1 yes, Q2 not really.

Comment: It will be helpful to write down exactly what the null and alternative hypotheses are, both for this and a regular ANOVA F-test (in regression form).

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that the 2 groups significantly differ with respect to the dependent variable?

If you run a regression where $z$ is a binary indicator for group membership, the the coefficient $\beta_2$ in the model

$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2z_i + \varepsilon_i$$

represents the difference in the expectation **conditioned on $x$**.

> How is this method conceptually different from running a simpler anova?

In the case where the grouping variable has several groups and you have no other covariables to adjust for ($x$ in the model above) then the regression model is exactly an ANOVA.